# Should I store data in a SESSION or use multiple Ajax calls?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, session

If I am retrieving large amounts of data from a database to be used on multiple sequential pages what is the best method for this?

For example at the moment I have a page with a form that calls a PHP script via it's action

This script searches a database full of customers, stores them in a session array and redirects back to the original page. The page then tests if the session is set and loops through the session array displaying each customer in a combo box.

The user moves to the next page where the array is used again to display the customers.

There will be multiple users accessing the database for this information ( only around 10 or so) sequentially

Would I be better off keeping it stored in the database and retrieving it from there every time I need it, rather than the SESSION?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only ten users to worry about you aren't going to notice a significant improvement or decline in performance either way.  That being said, if this data is dynamic, you would benefit from directly accessing it in case it changes in between pages.

Normally this would be done with caching (memcache, etc) but your situation is controlled enough not to require anything more than an SQL query.

This of course assumes your server was made in the past decade and can handle ten simulatneous users.  If your server performance is not up to the challenge I will revisit my answer.